# In MSTest How to access TestMethod exception in TestCleanup without using try/catch block in test method

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, stack-trace

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
    //Do required actions before every test
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {
         //Actual test
         Assert.AreEqual(1, 0);
    }

[TestCleanup]
public void TearDown()
{
//If TestMethod has failed - Get the exeception thrown by the TestMethod. So based on this I can take some action?
}
```

I am able to get TestMethod Name, Test outcome from TestContext. However I want to get the stacktrace of TestMethod in TestCleanup.

Secondly I know one way of achiving this is by wraping test method steps in a try / catch block and setting the exception to a variable or a property and acessing it in tear down.

However I do not want to wrap each and every testmethod in try/catch block. Is there any other cleaner approach available?

I would appriciate a little detailed explaination or an example as I am a novice in MSTest and programming.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this yet?

Comment: The only possibility seems to implement your own `TestExecutionExtension`. This alone is easy, however you must also create a separate assembly, which's path needs to be added somewhere in the system's registry (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2009/09/04/extending-the-visual-studio-unit-test-type-part-1/), bleh...

Comment: Five years later, if you still have this issue, the psuedo-answer can be found here. What you're wanting isn't natively supported, but can be achieved through appdomain events. It's ugly but it works and can be shoved into a base class where no one ever needs to know about it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39208343/2254971

Comment: Hi Everyone, Do we have any solution from MS for accessing exception info thrown by a test to  access it in Test Clean up  or are we still doing things our way!